# Can't get into the admin console after migrating to new server

Tags: wordpress, administration

I migrated my WordPress blog to a new server, and everything seemed to be working fine until it started giving me the error when entering the admin area:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 4864 bytes) in
/home/neworder/public_html/blog/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php
on line 729
```

The line 729 has:

```
$protected = array( '_wp_attached_file', '_wp_attachment_metadata', '_wp_old_slug', '_wp_page_template' );
```

I had installed the maintenance-mode, and I have suspicions that this is what broke the forum.

If I remove the plugin it then gives another error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 19456 bytes) in
/home/neworder/public_html/blog/wp-admin/includes/post.php
on line 1158
```

And that line has:

```
$content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js">' . esc_html__( 'Remove featured image' ) . '</p>';
}
```

I tried to restore the blog file-system from the old server and also to restore the database from the old server (2x), but still it gives me the same error.

The blog itself seems to be working fine:

http://blog.antinovaordemmundial.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at this:
http://nabtron.com/wordpress-3-0-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted/1924/

Comment: Just as a side note there is a stack exchange site specifically for Wordpress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh interesting I didnt know that

Comment: Just to add the full answer, you need to add this:

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

After DB_COLLATE config.